# send mpi message from a c++ code to fortran 90 code

Tags: c++, mpi, fortran90, openmpi

I am try to see if I can send the contents of an array in a c++ code to a fortran 90 code. I'm using openmpi 1.4.3 built using intel 11.1.072 compilers. They are installed on Linux version 2.6.18-108chaos (mockbuild@chaos4builder1) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)).

Here is the c++ side:

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include <iostream>
# include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

void printarray (float arg[], int length) {
   for (int n=0; n<length; n++)
    cout << arg[n] << " ";
  cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
   float a[10];
   int myrank,i;
   MPI::Init ( argc, argv );
   myrank=MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
   cout << "rank "<<myrank<<" is c++ rank."<<std::endl;
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      a[i]=10.0;
   }
   printarray(a,10);
   MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&a[0],1,MPI::DOUBLE_PRECISION,1,100);
   MPI::Finalize();
}
```

and here is the f90 side:

```
program main
implicit none
include "mpif.h"
integer:: ierr,stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
real(8):: a(10)

call mpi_init(ierr)
a=0
print*,a
call mpi_recv(a(1),10,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD,stat,ierr)
print*,a
call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program
```

after I've compiled the two codes, I run with

```
$mpirun -n 1 *c_executable* : -n 1 *fortran_executable* > output
```

The numbers I get on the fortran side are not 10.0.

Comment: Don't use the MPI C++ bindings! They are **removed** in the draft 2 version of the MPI 3.0 specification and this change would most likely make it to the final 3.0 standard. Use the C bindings instead - they are quite similar to one for Fortran. Also use the MPI module interface in Fortran: `USE mpi` instead of `include "mpif.h"`.

Answer (score 4):

The MPI standard indeed has provisions for language interoperability - the whole §16.3 of the MPI 2.2 document is dedicated to language interoperability between Fortran and C.

> §16.3.10 Interlanguage Communication
>
> The type maching rules for communications in MPI anr not changed: the datatype specification for each item sent should match, in type signature, the datatype specification used to receive this item (unless one of the types is `MPI_PACKED`). Also, the type of a message item should match the type declaration for the corresponding communication buffer location, unless the type is `MPI_BYTE` or `MPI_PACKED`. Interlanguage communication is allowed if it complies with these rules.

Then it goes on to show an example where the same construced datatype is used to send a message from a Fortran code and to receive it in a piece of C code. The type is constructed so as to allow the C code to receive the data into a buffer that belongs to the Fortran code, but what is more relevant to your question is that the C code uses a datatype that was constructed from the Fortran `MPI_REAL`. Using Fortran datatypes in C functions and vice versa is perfectly legal if it makes sense:

> §16.3.6 MPI Opaque Objects - Datatypes
>
> ... If a datatype defined in one language is used for a communication call in another language, then the message sent will be identical to the message that would be sent from the first language: the same communication buffer is accessed, and the same representation conversion is performed, if needed. All predefined datatypes can be used in datatype constructors in any language. If a datatype is committed, it can be used for communication in any language.

(predefined MPI datatypes like `MPI_REAL` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are committed)

On the contrary, using Fortran datatypes on the one side and C datatypes on the other is allowed but considered not portable:

> §16.3.10 Interlanguage Communication
>
> ... MPI implementations may weaken these type matching rules, and allow messages to be sent with Fortran types and received with C types, and vice versa, when those types match. I.e., if the Fortran type `INTEGER` is identical to the C type `int`, then an MPI implementation may allow data to be sent with datatype `MPI_INTEGER` and be received with datatype `MPI_INT`. *However, such code is not portable.*

(emphasis mine)

Changing `REAL(8)` to `DOUBLE PRECISION` does nothing to increase the portablity of your code as the Fortran standard guarantees nothing about the representation of the `DOUBLE PRECISION` type - it only says that `DOUBLE PRECISION` is an alternative specifier for one kind of `REAL` type, namely the double precision kind, which should have greater decimal precision than the default real. Sending `REAL(8)` with a datatype of `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` is not portable. Instead a portable program would use the `SELECTED_REAL_KIND` intrinsic of Fortran together with `MPI_Type_create_f90_real` to register a matching MPI datatype.

The best option IMHO is to rely on the language interoperability between C and Fortran and stick to the same datatypes on both sides. Since your compiler suite is recent enough, you can use the `ISO_C_BINDING` mechanism of Fortran to get `REAL` and `INTEGER` kinds, compatible with C, and use the C datatypes in the Fortran calls. For example:

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
REAL(C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(10) :: darray
INTEGER(C_INT) :: ival
...
CALL MPI_SEND(darray, 10, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
CALL MPI_BCAST(ival, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
...
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness!   "Changing REAL(8) to DOUBLE PRECISION does nothing to increase the portablity" -- well, it does, as REAL(8) doesn't necessarily exist (or mean what one might expect) for all compilers, whereas double precision does.   OTOH, the BIND(C) is a good idea, but in practice, for any machine you can imagine computing on today, the floating point representation is going to be the same for Fortran or C -- a bigger worry might be going cross-architecture for the two programs (little- to big-endian) for which you have to jump through different sets of hoops entirely.

Comment: @JonathanDursi, most generic MPI implementations (including Open MPI) support heterogeneous environments (in Open MPI it is a configure-time option, disabled by default for performance reasons) and will do automagic representation conversion (endinanness, etc.) on the fly of data sent between nodes with different architectures. It should be possible to handle gracefully such scenario using the portable C types and their `ISO_C_BINDING` counterparts and stay within what MPI datatype system allows (e.g. no fancy things with `MPI_BYTE`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this; the main problem is that in your C++ code, your `a` array is of type `float`, not double.

You're also only sending 1, not 10, of these not-doubles; the `MPI_RECV()` would still work, but of course the other 9 values wouldn't be set.

Something else that you should note is that you should use `MPI_DOUBLE` in C/C++, and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` in Fortran; they need not be the same, and in fact I imagine the use of `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` in C is undefined.

You also probably want to use `double precision` in the fortran program rather than `real(8)`, which is common but not standard.

In principle, you would even want to worry about heterogeneity, about the encoding of the floating point numbers on the machines running the two programs, but for most of us this isn't an issue.

Comment: I changed the array to double precision in the fortran code, and to double in the c++ code, and set the c++ mpi data type to mpi::double, and the array was successfully communicated to the fortran side. I think you are right in that mpi_double_precision may be undefined in c. Thanks!

Comment: Mixing MPI datatypes from different languages is more than defined in the standard - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified working version in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int i,ierr, num_procs, my_id;
  double a[10];

  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a[i]=10.0;
  }

  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  printf(" Hello C Code\n"); 

  /**/
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
  ierr = MPI_Send(&a[0],10,MPI_DOUBLE,1,100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  


  ierr = MPI_Finalize(); 

}
```

Here is a modified working version in F

```
    program main
        use mpi

        implicit none
        integer:: ierr,stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
        double precision:: a(10)

        call mpi_init(ierr)

        write(*,*)"Hello F Code"
        a=0
        print*,a
        call mpi_recv(a(1),10,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD,stat,ierr)
        print*,a
        call mpi_finalize(ierr)
    end program
```